# Laravel Breeze Vue - Link and page not rendering

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-breeze

I working on an app and using Laravel Breeze Vue for the first time. Just some quick background, Laravel Breeze provides some quick scaffolding for authentication. When a user logs in, they are presented with a simple dashboard page. I have added a new link to this page as per below.

**app/resources/js/Layouts/Authenticated.vue**

```html
<!-- Navigation Links -->
<div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
  <BreezeNavLink :href="route('dashboard')" :active="route().current('dashboard')">
    Dashboard
  </BreezeNavLink>
  <BreezeNavLink :href="route('client.index')" :active="route().current('client.index')">
    Clients
  </BreezeNavLink>
</div>
```

I have also created an Index.vue file at file path **app/resources/js/Pages/Client/Index.vue**. It looks like below:

```html
<template>
  <Head title="Clients" />

  <BreezeAuthenticatedLayout>
    <template #header>
      <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        Clients
      </h2>
    </template>

    <div class="py-12">
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
          <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
            You're logged in!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </BreezeAuthenticatedLayout>
</template>

<script>
import BreezeAuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/Authenticated.vue'
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

export default {
  components: {
    BreezeAuthenticatedLayout,
    Head,
  },
}
</script>
```

I am using a route resource in my **web.php** file as per below. I have confirmed that client.index is an existing route via `php artisan route:list`.

```js
//client routing
Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function() {
  Route::resource('client', ClientController::class);
});
```

I am facing two problems. The first problem is that the link will not render in my navigation links. The second issue is that the Index.vue page will not render as well. I have tried doing `npm run dev`, `npm run watch` and clearing caches. None of these have worked. Please provide me with some insight on how to address these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is closed. I'm using old hardware and it was taking time to pick up the changes. `npm run dev` performed as expected.